# Как с помощью Stream API получить сумму всех ключей Map умноженных на значения?

Tags: java, java-stream

Подскажите пожалуйста имеется

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> denominations=new HashMap<>();
```

Где ключ - номинал купюры, значение - количество.
Каким образом используя Stream можно получить сумму всех Ключей умноженных на значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

примерно так

```
Map<Integer, Integer> denominations=new HashMap<>();
denominations.put(1,2);
denominations.put(3,4);

int sum = denominations.keySet().stream()
        .mapToInt(key -> denominations.get(key) * key)
        .sum();

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Спасибо....................

Comment: @Alexandr [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: поставьте себе Intellij IDEA это среда из обычных конструкций может подобные генерировать по клику